# Pinterest Widget: Add Any Image on Page Pin It Option

Tags: widget, pinterest

I am using the code generator for the Pin It widget here: http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#

and have selected the "Add any image on page" option.  However the widget shows me a blank rectangle when I try to use the button to pin. There are 6+ images on the page, all with a direct URL (including http://).  When I read through the [documentation here](https://help.pinterest.com/entries/21101982-Adding-the-Pin-It-Button-to-your-website#pincontentguidelines), it says an image must be selected for it to work, but when you select the "add any image on page" option it doesn't ask you to specify an image.

How can I make this work so users can pin any image on the page?  Anyone else have this problem?  I would expect this option to function similarly to the Pin It Bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script tag is located right before the closing body tag, if you include the script in the head tag, you won't get the list of images.

This is noted on the page where you generate the code (http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button) but it is easy to miss!